# Flow resuming in mulesoft

Tags: mule

Problem I am facing is I am using a for each component for iterating the records one by one and then inserting in to some end system.
What exactly is happening is when the data is correct it inserts the data into end system but as there is some exception in the data , exception handling code is executed but the flow do not resumes back in for loop so that all other records gets executed.
I have tried adding sublow and then calling it from flow  but while adding a exception handling in sub flow gives me error as **"invalid content in custom or catch or choice exception handling"**

How to resumes the flow after executing the exception/error handling block. 
.

Comment: Just adding to what Dds said. You can add exception strategy on private flow (a normal flow without endpoint). By having exception strategy there, the exception will be caught inside that private flow and when it returns to calling flow, the calling flow should resumes.

Answer (score 0):

SubFlows can't have endpoints or exception strategies that's why you're getting this error.

Never the less you could just use a normal flow instead of your subflow. 
If it has no endpoint then it's call a private flow and can only be referenced from inside your application.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with two options here. 
1. Use batch processing which can give you list of elements which are processed either successfully and failed.
2. Use until success scope

Answer (score 0):

First, remember that as soon as a processor in ANY scope (flow, try, etc.) raises an error, after the error handler runs (regardless of the level of the handler: app-default, flow-scope, or try-scope) and regardless of whether the error-scope in the error-handler is On Error Propogate or On Error Continue, NO, repeat NO, other processors in that scope are executed.

The pattern that gets you what you want his this:

1. Wrap a processor (or series of processors) in a given scope into a Try Scope. (note, the easiest way to do this is to select the desired processors, right-click, and in the pop-up, click "Wrap in..." and then in the resulting fly-out - "try".
2. Drop an On Error Continue error-scope into the Error Handling section of the Try Scope.
3. Handle the error however you want in the error-scope. This can include NO processors, which treats the error as a no-op.

Thus, when the processor of concern throws the error, no further processors in that Try Scope get called, BUT, after running the Try Scope's On Error Continue error-scope's processor, processing will continue in the parent scope (in this case the flow) and you get to keep processing the elements in your collection.

NOTE: It is correct that a Subflow cannot have an error handler of its own. HOWEVER, it is important to point out that Subflows run in the context of their parent / calling scope (e.g. a Flow / Private Flow), which CAN have error handlers. So, if you have Flows A and B with their error-handlers A' and B', and Subflow C, and Flows A and B each call Subflow C through a flow reference, and further suppose you have processor P1 in C that flows an error, THEN:

- When P1 runs being called from Flow A, control passes to A'
- When P1 runs being called from Flow B, control passes to B'.

NOTE2: Until Successful will not help the iteration. It will only repeat the attempt to send the data until the processor doing so no longer errors.  That does not seem to be what the O.P. was asking, though my interpretation may be wrong.